# couchbase where can I execute cbq command

Tags: couchbase

I have a couchbase server and I want to connect to it from my query engine. I asked a lot and I found that I have to use this command

```
 ./cbq-engine -couchbase http://--couchbase-server-name--:8091/
```

regarding that I have many questions about that command, like where should I put the username and password, why should I use the port 8091 when my server is working online so port is 8080, I don't want the answer of those questions, but I **need** to know where should I execute that command?

I tried on cmd on but I got that cbq is not defined.

I am on windows  7 64bit

please help

Comment: What query engine is that? Couchbase has got a lot client SDK:s for many platforms.

Comment: @folkol yes I know and I am already using the skd for pythong and java but i am asking about querying my server like the n1q1 does with its data using browser. got me please? if not please check my previous question

Comment: Couchbase has got a GUI, by default on port :8091, you can use that to inspect the documents (And more).

Comment: Also, I think that you can specify the username and password in the URL. Like http://myuser:mypass@servername:8091. That works with the command line tool at least.

Comment: @folkol but I can't use that to query my document on my server, right? that 8091 is for document on localhost on `data` folder, not for real data on my server witch is a couchbase server online

Comment: You will have to browse port :8091 on one of the servers in the cluster, yes.

Comment: @folkol do you mean editing the start_tutorla.bat to include the username and password? and what about my online server please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60990/discussion-between-folkol-and-re-re-re-re).

Comment: @folkol do you get me please? lets say that my server is http://www.iamtried.com and i have a username = `name` and and a password = `ps`. How can I use that 8091 tool to query my server? that 8091 is just for local data

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on windows, I believe the difference is that it's cbq.exe and you'll need to have it in  your path or be in that directory.  The downloads as posted at http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql do have cbq.exe included:

`.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README
├── cbq-engine.exe
├── cbq.exe
├── data
├── start_tutorial.bat
└── static
2 directories, 5 files`

Also note that the Java 2.0, node.js 2.0 and some other SDKs have experimental support for N1QL querying.